# Conditional Sum in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

what is the linq query from this sql query

```
SELECT 
      sum(IIF(jenis = 'primer',1,0)) as sum_primer, 
      sum(IIF(jenis = 'sekunder',1,0)) as sum_sekunder
FROM cooperations
```

Try to search same example from 101 Linq Samples, but got no clue

**UPDATE**
So, I using this query in my C#

```
var query = (from c in db_cooperations.cooperations
              group c by c.jenis into g
              select
              (new
              {
                sum_primer = g.Count(c => c.jenis == "primer"),
                sum_sekunder = g.Count(c => c.jenis == "sekunder")
              })).ToArray();
```

The output are

```
 sum_primer   sum_sekunder
    0             0 
    0             52
   250            0
    0             0
    0             0
```

So, how I could remove the zero value, and just return one row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var sum_primer = cooperations.Count(c => c.jenis == "primer");
var sum_secunder = cooperations.Count(c => c.jenis == "sekunder");
```

Or in single query to database

```
var query = (from c in cooperations
             where c.jenis == "primer" || c.jenis == "sekunder"
             group c by c.jenis
             select new { Jenis = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }
            ).ToDictionary(x => x.Jenis, x => x.Count);

var result = new {
   sum_primer = query.ContainsKey("primer") ? query["primer"] : 0,
   sum_sekunder = query.ContainsKey("sekunder") ? query["sekunder"] : 0
};
```

This SQL will be generated (and only two rows will be returned):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Count], [t0].[jenis] AS [Jenis]
FROM [cooperations] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[jenis] = 'sekunder') OR ([t0].[jenis] = 'primer')
GROUP BY [t0].[jenis]
```

Comment: Your query returning right value, but because I have 10 condition, does it mean, I have to do 10 query? Thanks :D

Comment: @l1th1um if you mean 10 conditions for `jenis` then actually executed query will be only one (see update)

Answer (score 5):

you can achieve it like this , following is provide you count of the items as per condition

```
var data = db.CoOperations.
           GroupBy(x=>x.jenis )
           .select (new {
                sum_primer = g.Count(c => c.jenis == "primer"),
                sum_sekunder = g.Count(c => c.jenis == "sekunder"),
            });
```

Comment: That is simple grouping which will return `sum_primer` and `sum_sekunder` for each `jenis` value.